# Finding the value of c for a two variable function to allow continuity.

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis, limits, multivariable-calculus, continuity

The function f:$\mathbb{R^2}$$\to$$\mathbb{R}$ given by
$$f(x,y)=\begin{cases}\frac{xy^2}{x^2+y^2} & \text{if } (x,y) \neq (0,0) \\
c & \text{if }(x, y) = 0\end{cases}.$$

I am trying to calculate the limit (by any means) to determine the value of constant $c$ such that $f$ is continuous at $(0,0)$.

I have obtained the limit for
$$f(x,y)=\frac{xy^2}{x^2+y^2} \quad \text{if } (x,y) \neq (0,0)$$ through using polar coordinates $L=0$.

I do not know how to find $c$ from here.

Comment: Also, apologies for the incorrect entry of the piecewise function, I did not know how to enter it correctly.

Comment: This is achieved through the cases environment in Latex/Mathjax. You can press edit to play around with the code.

Comment: For continuity at the origin, you need that $$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}f(x,y)=f(0,0)=c$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Observe that $$\left | \frac {xy^2} {x^2+y^2} \right | \leq \sqrt {x^2+y^2} < \varepsilon$$ whenever $\sqrt {x^2 + y^2} < \delta,$ where $\delta = \varepsilon.$

So $$\lim\limits_{(x,y) \rightarrow (0,0)} \frac {xy^2} {x^2 + y^2} = 0.$$

For the continuity of $f$ at $(0,0)$ we should have $c=f(0,0) = \lim\limits_{(x,y) \rightarrow (0,0)} \frac {xy^2} {x^2 + y^2} = 0.$

Comment: Is there another way to do this without using the epsilon-delta definition? I don't really understand it.

Comment: You are studying multivariable calculus without knowing $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ definition of limit!!

Comment: Unfortunately I just don't understand how to apply it. We have been taught it but have not had to use it and when I have practiced I just do not know what values for epsilon or delta i'm meant to be using.

Comment: No matter which $\varepsilon>0$ you take you will get some $\delta>0$ depending on that $\varepsilon.$ In this case $\delta = \varepsilon.$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Use that $$\frac{x^2+y^2}{2}\geq |xy|$$

Answer (score 0):

Do you that something that converges to zero times something bounded converges to zero? Well:

$$\frac{|xy^2|}{x^2+y^2}=|x|\frac{y^2}{x^2+y^2}\le|x|\frac{x^2+y^2}{x^2+y^2}\ldots$$

Comment: OP has already found the limit

Comment: @ShubhamJohri I know that...sort of, as he doesn't seem to be quite sure, otherwise it'd be trivial to know what $\;c\;$ must be. This, I hope, could help him.